# How do I make a div stick to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I am making a voting system. When user click on a link with class "vote" a voting box appears just belov the clicked link. It looks like this at the moment:

[image]

My problem is that if the page is scrolled then the vote box is not positioned correctly. I want it to always appear just below the link and to stick to the link even when page is scrolled.

My container is styled like this:

```
#vote_container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 82px;
    min-height: 83px;
    background-color: #e7edf3;
    border: 3px solid #d3d6d8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 40%;
    margin-top: 6px;    
    padding: 10px;    
    text-align: left;
    top: 60%;
    z-index: 199;    
}
```

And this is the code I use to position the container:

```
var pos = $(this).offset();
var width = $(this).width();        
$("#vote_container").css({ "left": (pos.left - 16) + "px", "top": (pos.top + 28) + "px" });
```

Ive even created a [simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/xkNqG/1/) at jsFiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does changing the #vote_container position to absolute resolve your issue?
http://jsfiddle.net/xkNqG/9/

**EDIT:**
Also, in the css I added `display:none` and in the function added $('#vote_container').show()

Comment: Perfect - thank you (I allready tried it but in my sandbox envioriment the container were placed in the page content and not working).

Comment: If I could suggest. Add a body click event to hide the #vote_container in case the 'X' is too difficult for you users to use.

Answer (score 1):

The #vote_container should not be 'position: fixed' as ngen says it should instead be 'position: absolute'  [here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkNqG/12/)  I simplified your css (for temporary purposes) just to help get to the root of the problem and added more text so that the fiddle would actually demonstrate the scroll problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure css solution try this.

css

```
.tipLink{
  color:#33f;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}
.tip{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  top:80%;
  left:110%;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  color:black;
  z-index:20;
  padding:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align:center;
}
.tipLink:hover .tip{
  display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="tipLink">
  Mouse Over Me
  <span class="tip">Hello World</span>
</span>
```

You will have to style the inner span tag to the design you need, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the jQuery tooltip plugin, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip, and enhance it by styling it the way you want. It already handles positioning and can have text or markup in it.